# How do I compare a list with an interger?

Tags: python, replit

This is what code I currently have (But in simplified form):

```
Example = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Test = random.randint(0,len(Exmaple))
if Example[Test] == 1:
    print("Working")
else:
    print("Not Working")
```

I want it to print "Working" by detecting if it lands on the integer 1
I could do Example[4] but I want to change the amount of items there are in the list, so it would work if I changed Example to [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Comment: Instead of choosing a random index, you can choose a random element directly: `if random.choice(Example) == Test`

Answer (score 0):

by changing `if Example[Test] == 1:` to `random.choice(Example) == 1:` it allows the code to print "Working" if it detects the interger 1

DeepSpace answered this in an [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999002/how-do-i-compare-a-list-with-an-interger/71999179#comment127221855_71999002):

> Instead of choosing a random index, you can choose a random element directly: `if random.choice(Example) == Test`